# Multicast a file to a group of users

Tags: java, json

I have a problem to send a file to a group of users. Users **could** receive the file was sent from server but the file **would not** be saved if it is **less than 8kb**. 
Here is the code:

MulticastSocketServer

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MulticastSocketServer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName;
    String address = "235.0.0.1";
    int port = 2222;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter file name : ");
    fileName = in.next();


try (DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket()) {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName + ".txt"));

        DatagramPacket fn = new DatagramPacket(fileName.getBytes(),fileName.getBytes().length, addr, port);
        serverSocket.send(fn); 

        DatagramPacket msgPacket = null;
        String txt = "";

        while((txt = br.readLine())!=null){
            msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(txt.getBytes(),txt.getBytes().length, addr, port);
            serverSocket.send(msgPacket); 
            System.out.println(txt);
        }
    }catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

MulticastSocketClient

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MulticastSocketClient {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    int port = 2222;
    String address = "235.0.0.1";
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);
    byte[] buf = new byte[64];
    byte[] buf2 = null ;

    try (MulticastSocket clientSocket = new MulticastSocket(port)){
        clientSocket.joinGroup(addr);

        DatagramPacket fn = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        clientSocket.receive(fn);
        String name = new String(buf, 0, buf.length);
        String fileName = name.trim();

        try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new      FileWriter(fileName+"2.txt"))){

        while (true) {
            buf2 = new byte [1024];
            DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf2, buf2.length);
            clientSocket.receive(msgPacket);
            String msg = new String(buf2,0,buf2.length);
            String txt = msg.trim();
            pw.println(txt);
            System.out.println(txt);  
        }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

}

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: hi there, no I dont...

Comment: "Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileName + ".txt");" is useless. Should be removed from the question

Comment: Yup, I forgot to remove it T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never exiting the `while (true)` loop, because you don't have any mechanism for transmitting end of stream, so you're never closing the `PrintWriter`, so it isn't flushing its final buffer, so any file < 4096 chars won't get flushed at all, so it will be zero length.

However your code has much worse problems that this. You are assuming:

- the filename fits into 1024 characters
- every line of the input file fits into 1024 bytes
- the filename is received first
- all the content packets are received
- all the content packets are received in order
- all the content packets are received exactly once
- the length of every datagram is 1024
- the data is text, not binary, and can be converted losslessly to a String

You're using UDP. That means that most of these assumptions are invalid.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problems of my code, but I thought with this line of code 
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new      FileWriter(fileName+"2.txt")))
would help me to close PrintWriter automatically... I use UDP because it is my assignment..

Comment: It would, if you could ever get out of that infinite loop, but you can't. See edit. If you must use UDP, use it correctly, and be aware of its limitations, It isn't a stream.

Comment: You are definitely right! Could you please tell me how I should terminate the loop ? I really appreciate your help

Comment: @stephenleow That requires you to pay *design* attention to every one of the points I listed above, and also to the fact that UDP is a datagram protocol, not a stream protocol. It isn't just a ,matter of adjusting your code slightly.

Comment: Problem solved !!! How silly I am... You have already given me hints to solve the problems... Thanks EJP !!! I cannot find the words to thank you for all you have done !